# Ignore case sensitivity while selecting option from a dropdown in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a problem to select from dropdown menu by using `selectByVisibleText` ignoring case sensitivity. The options' case is dynamic.

Example Code that I have used :

```
public static void setDropdownValue(By fieldId, String fieldValue) {
    Select dropDown = new Select(driver.findElement(fieldId));
    dropDown.selectByVisibleText(fieldValue);
}
```

Is there a way I can select option from the menu ignoring cases.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible using `selectByVisibleText(text)` but if you still want to do it somehow. Use something like this:

```
public static void setDropdownValue(By fieldId, String fieldValue) {
Select dropDown = new Select(driver.findElement(fieldId));
int index = 0;
    for (WebElement option : dropDown.getOptions()) {
        if (option.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(fieldValue))
            break;
        index++;
    }
    dropDown.selectByIndex(index);
}
```

One last point to add, depending on the structure of you web page sometimes `option.getText()` may not return with the option value that you need.

In such cases find the attribute which contains the value of options in the drop down and use `option.getAttribute("the attribute name containing value")`. Typically for Select the attribute is 'value', for it you must use `option.getAttribute("value")`

I hope it helps :)

Comment: Prateek.. Thanks a lot for your help. I used the code you provided and it worked . However, for some options when there is a '/' in the text getText() doesn't work. I wanted to use one function for all the drop downs in the application and I cannot use getAttribute ("value") as the value returned is different from getText().Is there a way to sovle this ?

Comment: Hi Tashi... I'm glad that it helped..! 
Talking about the second issue you are getting, I'm not quite clear with what exactly the issue is.. Please help me with an example and the error you are getting.. please try to elaborate if possible?

Answer (score 0):

**No**, not with `selectByVisibleText(text)`, which gets turned into:

```
findElements(By.xpath(".//option[normalize-space(.) = " + Quotes.escape(text) + "]"));
```

**Reference:** https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.java#L112